# Problem 10 chapter 1 from RCA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$, $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded complex measurable functions on $X$, an $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X$. Prove that $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu=\int \limits_{X}fd\mu,$$ and show that the hypothesis "$\mu(x)<\infty$" cannot be omitted.

**Proof:** It's enough to prove it for real-valued case.

If $\mu(X)=0$ then obvious.

Suppose that $0<\mu(X)<\infty$. For $\forall \varepsilon>0$ $\exists N_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that for any $n\geqslant N$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\mu(X)}$ on $X$. Then $\int \limits_{X}|f_n-f|d\mu\leqslant \int \limits_{X}\dfrac{\varepsilon}{\mu(X)}d\mu=\varepsilon$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}|f_n-f|d\mu=0 \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left|\int \limits_{X}(f_n-f)d\mu\right|=0 \Rightarrow \lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}(f_n-f)d\mu=0$$ Also $\exists M\geqslant 0$  such that $|f_n|\leqslant M$ then $f_n\in L^1(\mu)$ and $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Hence the last limit equality we can write in the following form: $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu=\int \limits_{X}fd\mu$

*Counterexample:* Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu):=(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}}, |\cdot|)$ and $A_n=[1,n]\cap \mathbb{N}$ where $|\cdot|$ - counting measure on $2^{\mathbb{N}}$.
Note that $\mu(\mathbb{N})=\infty$. Let $f_n=\dfrac{1_{A_n}}{n}$. We see that $f_n$ is measurable and bounded.
Also $f_n\to 0$ uniformly on $X$. Hence $$1=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\int \limits_{X}f_nd\mu\neq\int \limits_{X}fd\mu=0$$

Are my proof and example are correct? Would be very grateful for remarks!

Comment: Looks good. I would write the inequalities as $| \int (f_n-f)| \le \int | f_n-f|$, then since $|f| \le |f_n-f|+|f_n|$ it follows that $f$ is integrable and hence $\int (f_n-f)=\int f_n - \int f$. Another counterexample is $f_n = {1 \over n} 1_{[0,n]}$, $f=0$, then $f_n \to f$ uniformly, but $\int f_n = 1$, $\int f = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Thanks for checking out!